# Why is the "black" text on my Mac made up of so many different colors?

Tags: mac, text, color

My Mac has this nifty "zoom" function that kicks in when I hold control and scroll in and out.   If I zoom all the way in on black text on my screen, it is made up of many different colors.  Why is this?

[image: Here is an example of the colors]

Answer (score 1):

The Mac is rendering text using subpixel resolution. See these explanations for instance:

- [Font smoothing, anti-aliasing, and sub-pixel rendering](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/06/12.html)
- [Font smoothing explained](http://szafranek.net/works/articles/font-smoothing-explained/)